# linkedList is empty although elements added to it

Tags: java, linked-list

I created a "frame1" that contains a button , so if I click on that button , button action performed method will check if the LinkedList is empty , if is ,it will set the "addEmployee" frame visible which contains radioButton calls addEmployees_Auto, and when clicked , it will invoke method "add_Auto" from frame1 . This should fill the linkedList in frame1, but if I re-clicked on the button again , the LinkedList is empty again. why?
shouldn't the LinkedList be fill ??

this is "frame1"

```
public class Frame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    LinkedList <Employee>list2=new LinkedList <Employee>();
        ....

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    System.out.println("size="+list2.size());

    if(list2.isEmpty())
      new AddEmployees.setVisible(true);
}

public void addEmployees_Auto()
     {

        list2.add(new Employee(20910733,"Ahmed","Manager",2700));
        list2.add(new Employee(20910835,"Omar","Teaacher",2100));
        list2.add(new Employee(20910674,"Mohammed","Manager",3000));
        list2.add(new Employee(20910955,"Kareem","",2700));
        list2.add(new Employee(20910921,"Ameer","teacher",2500));

     }
}
```

AddEmployee frame :

```
public class AddEmployees extends javax.swing.JFrame {
             ...

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    
 {                                         

     if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()){

        new Frame1().addEmployees_Auto();
        this.setVisible(false);
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is your `add_Auto` method?

Comment: this `new AddEmployees.setVisible(true);` shouldn't even compile... How can you run this code??

Comment: this interaction of the two classes looks weird, can you explain what are you trying to achieve ? and may be post some compileable minimal code code that reproduces the behaviour you are getting ?

Comment: @VishalK : I mean "addEmployees_Auto" method

Comment: @jlordo : why it shouldn't even compile ??

Comment: @CalmSea: Because the code you posted gives the error `AddEmployees.setVisible cannot be resolved to a type` at the line I mentioned previously `new AddEmployees.setVisible(true);`

Comment: @jlordo : mistake ,new AddEmployees().setVisible(true);

Comment: @A4L : I want, if the Linkedlist were empty, to invoke the second frame which invokes the method that fills the list, but every time the button is clicked , the list is empty .Why ??

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are doing:

```
new Frame1()
```

every time in your `AddEmployees` class, so each time a new linked list is being created, which is always going to be empty. You need to pass in a reference to the calling instance of `Frame1`, such as

```
new AddEmployees(this)
```

from the `Frame1` class, and add the appropriate constructor to your `AddEmployees` class, e.g.

```
public AddEmployees(JFrame parent) { ... }
```

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly , but did not work. But the array is empty after I invoke the addEmployees_Auto();